# Get a reference that went on this page

Tags: php

I need to get a reference that went on this page and then send it on the server.
I tried to add this field in my form

```
<input type="hidden" id="refferer_url" name="refferer_url" value="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">
```

but I get nothing, when I try to go to my page from other pages using link, value of this input is empty.
What's wrong?

Comment: just use `echo` before it

Comment: Try <?= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?

Comment: The name of the header, `Referer` is a misspelling that has endured over time and now we have to live with it – but “compensating” for that by doubling the `f` doesn’t really undo the damage … ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="refferer_url" name="refferer_url" value="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">
```

Echo it :

```
                                                                        //here
<input type="hidden" id="refferer_url" name="refferer_url" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">
```